# How to set up Gunicorn to display Django exceptions with Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, logging, gunicorn

edit: Added in Django logging, still does not push errors to gunicorn from Django.

I have a django project deployed to Heroku in a worker using gunicorn. I have included all flags/configurations that I am using below. The issue is that the logging in Heroku does not display any output from Django, and my project is running into some 502 errors, that I am unsure of how to debug. Gunicorn just is not displaying any logs whatsoever from Django/python.

Procfile:

```
release: python manage.py migrate backend
web: bin/boot
worker: gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -c /app/gunicorn.conf.py --log-file -
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```py
# gunicorn.conf.py
# Non logging stuff
workers = 3
# Whether to send Django output to the error log 
capture_output = True
# How verbose the Gunicorn error logs should be 
loglevel = "debug"
```

Logging in settings.py

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'gunicorn': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': '/opt/djangoprojects/reports/bin/gunicorn.errors',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 mb
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'gunicorn.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['gunicorn'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you running your web application as a `worker` process? That should be a _`web`_ process. And what is your existing `bin/boot` `web` process supposed to do?

Comment: bin/boot is a buildpack for react.
I wasn't sure what the difference was between worker and web, but its a worker because I had issues with regular access going to django when it should have been going to react @Chris